# How to to overwrite Properties of search fields of Smart Filter Bar using local annotation file

Tags: sapui5

I’m trying to overwrite smart filter bar search fields properties such as “Label”, “Required” using local annotations file

[image]

***Annotation file - annotation related to ArtcleNumber field***

```
<Annotations xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm"
Target="XXX/ArticleNumber"> 
<Annotation Term="Common.ValueList"> 
<Record> 
<PropertyValue Property="Label" String="Article"/> 
<PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath"
String="ArticleFilterSet"/> 
<PropertyValue Property="SearchSupported"
Bool="true"/> 
<PropertyValue Property="Parameters"> 
<Collection> 
<Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterOut"> 
<PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty"
PropertyPath="ArticleNumber"/> 
<PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty"
String="Article"/> 
</Record> 
<Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly"> 
<PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Article"/> 
</Record> 
</Collection> 
</PropertyValue> 
</Record> 

</Annotation> 
</Annotations>
```

But Label is not getting overwrite from annotation file. Still It is taken from back end service metadata file

Please Help me on this. thanks